# React: conditionally render element with ref as a prop, sometimes ref is lost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

Here are my components:

```
// parent component
const activeTextareaFieldRef = useRef(null);

return (
  <GroupField textareaRef={activeField.id === id ? activeTextareaFieldRef : null} />
)

// group field component
<>
  <DataResultValue ref={item.name === activeField.subFieldName ? textareaRef : null} />
</>
```

Even if both conditions (in parent and child) are true, the ref is sometimes lost and is set to null. How can I achieve always having the ref not equal to null? I fixed everything that I could and I'm 100% sure the conditions are true

Comment: Refs will only become active when the component has been mounted, so are you using any `useEffect` hook to check for this?

Comment: You should probably not conditionally assign React refs for this reason. Generate all the refs you needs ahead of time.

Comment: @Keith, yes I'm using this kind of a useEffect

Comment: @DrewReese, for example I have 400 elements, do you mean I should generate 400 refs?

Comment: Yes, precisely that. Without more context for what you are using the ref for though it's difficult to make any more/better/alternative suggestion. For example, it seems you are wanting to mark some component active, which is possible also with normal props.

Comment: @DrewReese, how would you do it with normal props, in my code I need to focus on the textarea and without refs I can't achieve that

Comment: That's one of the normal uses of React refs... I was just saying that without knowing what you are using the refs for it hard to suggest alternatives if refs weren't the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

If your task is just focusing particular field then maybe you will find this solution useful.

Stop passing conditional refs via props and create bool prop `isActive` for your `DataResultValue` component. Each instance of this component could store ref to corresponding input/textarea and put focus in it as soon as `isActive` prop gets true.

For example:

```
const DataResultValue = ({ value, isActive }) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef()
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive) {
      inputRef.current.focus()    
    }
  }, [isActive])
  
  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      defaultValue={value}
      style={{ color: isActive ? 'red' : null }}
    />
  )
}
```